# Python - CVXOPT: Unconstrained quadratic programming

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, python

I'm trying to use the cvxopt quadratic solver to find a solution to a Kernel SVM but I'm having issues. I'm back to solving a very simple quadratic program:

\begin{gather*}
    \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2}x^\intercal Px + q^\intercal P
\end{gather*}

I get the error `ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n`. As I don't specify `A` or `G` I thought the problem might come from the fact that `Rank(P) < n` but it's not the case as `P` is full-ranked. The code below reproduces this error:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxopt

n = 5

P = np.random.rand(n,n)
P = P.T + P + np.eye(n)
q = 2 * np.random.randint(2, size=n) - 1

P = cvxopt.matrix(P.astype(np.double))
q = cvxopt.matrix(q.astype(np.double))

print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(P))

solution = cvxopt.solvers.qp(P, q)
```

Complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):      
    solution = cvxopt.solvers.qp(P, q)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 4470, in qp
    return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, kktsolver = kktsolver, options = options)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 2013, in coneqp
    raise ValueError("Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n")
ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n
```

Any idea?

Comment: I believe this question is off-topic for this group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the [`qp()`](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/blob/master/src/python/coneprog.py#L4157-L4159) solver requires that the matrix $P$ is *positive semi-definite*.

You are initially generating $P$ as a matrix of random numbers: sometimes $P' + P + I$ will be positive semi-definite, but other times it will not.

The likelihood is you've run your code and been unlucky that $P$ does not meet this criterion. (It is possible to be lucky: if I set `np.random.seed(123)` first, then your code runs without error.)

As further evidence that this is the problem here, from the traceback I see that cvxopt attempts to do Cholesky factorisation using LAPACK's `potrf` routine, which fails and raises an `ArithmeticError`. The [documents](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/lapack.html#cvxopt.lapack.potrf) for this routine in cvxopt state that an `ArithmeticError` is indeed raised if the matrix is not positive definite.